# Is it possible to have stereo sound from an external mic on a Canon Vixia HF G20

Tags: video, recording, digital, audio, stereo

I have a Canon Vixia HF G20 and I cannot find anywhere in the manual about an external mic in stereo mode. The "advanced hot shoe" does support stereo and surround sound but through the Line In/Mic port on the camera I can't seem to produce stereo sound. My source is definitely stereo. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the source and how you have hooked it up.  That may allow me to clarify my answer further as it appears the camera should support it.

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem, I'm using a Uni-Directional Electret Condenser Microphone, with the cable it came with, and an adapter to fit the microphone port. On the camera I have the MIC terminal input set to MIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Using Commercially Available Microphones section on page 76 of the manual for the HF G20, it should be possible to connect a stereo microphone to the external mic connection.  There may be some problem with the kind of a source you are using or the way you are connecting it.

Answer (score 1):

Verify again that your source is indeed a stereo source and that your cabling is TRS cabling. I own this same camera and have been able to record audio in full stereo and also on only one side of the stereo spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

I have the G20 and VidPro Xm-55... u r going to go into custom audio settings and then go to audio mix and just mix about two clicks up on internal microphone and let the external to the rest- that way you get clean sound with stereo separation.
We do live music studio recording and when my overall level is set around 67/70 it seems to be perfect.